# Playframework get client IP from server, but not from cookies

Tags: java, ip, netty, playframework-2.2, server

I would like to obtain client IP. 
Base on that IP I would like to give an access to application.
Currently I am getting IP from cookies using this code:

```
/**
 * Gets the ip.
 *
 * @return the ip
 */
public static String getIP() {
    return Request play.mvc.Controller.request().remoteAddress();
}
```

But it is **insecure**, cause User can easily change it.

So I would like to obtain phisical IP addres from server connection instead of this one from cookie.

How can I achive this? Please help.

Comment: I've tested it. I could easily change ip address using this command in linux shell: `curl --header "X-Forwarded-For: 1.2.3.4" "localhost:9000"`

Comment: Are you mutually authenticating between client/server or operating in a trusted/closed environment? Authentication/access control based upon client IPs sounds like it could get you into trouble.  It is easy to spoof HTTP headers and also can be spoofed at just about all other levels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a cookie... anyway simplest solution I can think of is ... hiding your app under some light HTTP server as a proxy and use its access restriction rules, the benefits:

- light server shouldn't be a bottleneck as it's dedicated to this job
- it's probably awared of tricks and hacks that hackers tries to walk around the restrictions
- denied IPs doesn't even get into your app, so you're saving resources
- it helps in general to solve several other tasks

Finally servers treat forwarded IPs in special way, i.e. when header manipulated like you show with curl, Apache will forward is as a list:

`1.2.3.4,123.123.123.123`

so you can catch bad IP anyway...

Comment: I was thinking about that solution, but weren't sure of it. Thanks for Your help. I will implement it.